BBPress Customization with Custom Plugin
I have created a custom plugin, to do customization in BBPRESS templates, & Paid Membership Pro.. Everything other customization is working fine, But the template i want to show instead of bbpress default loop-topics.php template is not showing it /wp-content/plugins/pharmacy-membership-forum/pharmacy-membership-forum.php - Mian Plugin File /wp-content/plugins/pharmacy-membership-forum/includes/templates.php - the file where we are connecting loop-topics.php /wp-content/plugins/pharmacy-membership-forum/templates/bbpress/loop-topics.php - new template for loop-topics.php templates.php Code it appears that bbPress is not prioritizing your custom templates, or something else might be going wrong during the template loading process.
<?php
// Prevent direct access
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

// Hook into plugins_loaded to ensure bbPress is loaded
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'cmp_override_bbpress_templates');

/**
 * Function to override bbPress templates.
 */
function cmp_override_bbpress_templates() {
    // Add filter to override bbPress template parts
    add_filter('bbp_get_template_part', 'cmp_custom_template_parts', 10, 3);
}

/**
 * Filter to override bbPress templates.
 *
 * @param array  $templates Array of template paths.
 * @param string $slug      Template slug.
 * @param string $name      Template name.
 * @return array Modified array of template paths.
 */
function cmp_custom_template_parts($templates, $slug, $name) {
    $plugin_template_path = plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'templates/bbpress/';

    // Check for various templates and override them
    if ($slug === 'loop' && $name === 'topics') {
        $custom_template_path = $plugin_template_path . 'loop-topics.php';
        array_unshift($templates, $custom_template_path);
        
    }

    if ($slug === 'content' && $name === 'single-forum') {
        $custom_template_path = $plugin_template_path . 'content-single-forum.php';
        array_unshift($templates, $custom_template_path);
    }

    if ($slug === 'loop' && $name === 'single-topic') {
        $custom_template_path = $plugin_template_path . 'loop-single-topic.php';
        array_unshift($templates, $custom_template_path);
    }
    
    return $templates;
    
}

